# MySQL => MariaDB = PHP Errors Header/Library versions

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I managing a little vps of my own and I've recently moved from mysql to mariadb (5.3).

On some php test projects that usually worked under php5/mysql5, I get some header errors about MySQL versions.

```
  Headers and client library minor version mismatch. Headers:50158 Library:50303
```

My guess here is : MariaDB 5.3 is the Library, and the Headers is the libmysqlclient.

I don't know where I've failed when updating/installing (even tried remove mysql and only install mariadb) but it seems that it happens with the php-mysql package.

I've tried to use the -o from apt-get to configure --with-mysql=mariadb-devel as I've seen on a topic, but in fact, it seems I don't know how to configure php5-mysql package (I don't even know what does it do : configurations files or libraries ?)

Well to sum up, why is my PHP5 MySQL header still in 5.1 where the library is 5.3 ?

Thank you in advance for any help,
Lucas.

[ Plus ]
How can I recover the configure parameters from an apt-get install ?
I've got no results when i use :

```
php5 -i | grep configure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP5 MySQL header still in 5.1 where the library is 5.3 is because PHP was not recompiled with the new headers (nor it should be because 5.3 remains binary backward compatible).

The check in the driver in itself is wrong, or better say too overcautious. PHP (mysqli) is unique among MySQL drivers in that it would barf when minor version is higher than the one that was compiled in.

Here is [bug report for PHP MySQL driver](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60656)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and i solved it:
(I have Server version: 5.3.5-MariaDB-ga-mariadb113-log and php 5.4.0 installed on my server)
I  downloaded php 5.4.0 source and compiled mysql.so manually.
This is solution:

```
# cd /root/php-5.4.0/ext/mysql
# phpize
# ./configure --with-mysql=/usr --with-libdir=lib64/mysql
# make
```

mysql.so have been compiled without errors and works fine.
Note: MariaDB-devel package and php-devel package needed.